# Function invocation error showing exactly the data types i provided

Tags: web3.py, python

I Was trying to interact with a smart contract named clearingHouse and use the function "openPosition", I went ahead and matched the data types as they were described using python3 web3 package but I still get this error which shows I ve matched everything correctly

Could not identify the intended function with name `openPosition`, positional arguments with type(s) `(address,bool,bool,int,int,int,int,bytes)` and keyword arguments with type(s) `{}`.
Found 1 function(s) with the name `openPosition`: ['openPosition((address,bool,bool,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint160,bytes32))']
Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types.

as shown above all my data types match the ones that are required

thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem, but I can't find a solution yet. Maybe you managed to overcome it?

Upd: My problem was that the parameters had to be passed as an array with a tuple: `arg = [(...parameters...)]`. And also I incorrectly counted one of the function parameters and the number went beyond the boundaries of the type in solidity `(uint24)`. Therefore, I advise you to recalculate the call parameters again.